# VueJS binding class in template not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bulma

I'm learning VueJS and I want to make tab components. I have a main.js and index.html file as follows:

```js
Vue.component('tabs', {
  template: "<div><div class='tabs is-medium'><ul><li v-for='tabb in tabs' :class='{'is-active': tabb.selected}'><a href='#'>{{ tabb.name }}</a></li></ul></div><div class='tabs-details'> <slot></slot></div></div>",
  data() {
    return {tabs: []};
  },

  created() {
    this.tabs = this.$children;
  }
});

Vue.component('tab', {
  template: '<div><slot></slot></div>',
  props: {
    name: {required: true },
    selected: { default: false }
  }

})

new Vue({
  el: '#root'

});
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div id="root">

      <tabs>
        <tab name="Tab1" :selected="true">
          <h1>Tab1 content</h1>
        </tab>

        <tab name="Tab2">
          <h1>Tab2 content</h1>
        </tab>

        <tab name="Tab3">
          <h1>Tab3 content</h1>
        </tab>

      </tabs>
   </div>


  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is in class binding part (`:class='{'is-active': tabb.selected}'`). The code works when it's removed or when the binding is not used and class value remains the same (`class='is-active'`). I was wondering why the binding class is not working ?

Note: Single quotes are used everywhere in template because it's (apparently) the only way I can keep everything in template (thus between " ") in the editor Atom.

Comment: You're using single quotes for two different purposes: to delimit both the attribute value and the string within that value. Generally backticks are used to enclose a template and double quotes are used around attribute values, with single quotes used for JS strings.

Comment: I've thought about that but I don't have the choice. It's the only way I can keep everything in the template (between " "), at least in the ID I'm using: Atom. I've also tried the other way around (use double quotes everywhere and delimit the template between single quotes). Same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write this:

```
:class='{'is-active': tabb.selected}'
```

You're using single quotes for two different purposes. As soon as Vue encounters that second `'` it is going to think that the attribute value has ended. This ends up being equivalent to:

```
:class='{'
```

The usual convention is to use backticks (not to be confused with single-quotes) for templates, like this:

```
template: `
  <div>
    <div class="tabs is-medium">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="tabb in tabs" :class="{'is-active': tabb.selected}">
          <a href="#">{{ tabb.name }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-details">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
`,
```

If you really can't use backticks then just escape some double-quotes. So either one of these:

```
:class=\"{'is-active': tabb.selected}\"
```

or:

```
:class='{\"is-active\": tabb.selected}'
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I wanted to use the backticks but I was confusing it with single quotes..